# Django detail view not rendering static files

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-staticfiles

Hello my I have a Django project which works fine but the problem I usually get is from my Detail View, it does not render statics files. And when I check the output from my terminal I see that my Detail View url name is joined to my static/assets link.

My static settings

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(CORE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(CORE_DIR, 'apps/static/'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(CORE_DIR, 'media')
# Default user model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'

# My urls.py file

from django.urls import path
from .views import *

app_name = 'base'

urlpatterns = [
   path("", HomePage.as_view(), name="home"),
   path("jobs", Jobs.as_view(), name="jobs"),
   path('jobs-short', Jobs_List.as_view(), name="jobs-short-list"),
   path('job-detail/<int:pk>', Job_Detail.as_view(), name='job-detail'),
   path("company", Company.as_view(), name="companies"),
   path('candidate', Candidate.as_view(), name="candidates"),
   path('candidate-detail/<int:pk>', CandidateDetail.as_view(), name="candidate-detail"),
   path("about-us", about_us, name="about"),
   path("candidates", candidates, name="candidate"),
   
]


[28/Dec/2022 21:32:03] "GET /job-detail/static/assets/css/plugins.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4068
Not Found: /job-detail/static/assets/css/style.css
[28/Dec/2022 21:32:03] "GET /job-detail/static/assets/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4062
Not Found: /job-detail/static/assets/css/templete.css
[28/Dec/2022 21:32:03] "GET /job-detail/static/assets/css/templete.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4071
Not Found: /job-detail/static/assets/css/skin/skin-1.css
[28/Dec/2022 21:32:03] "GET /job-detail/static/assets/css/skin/skin-1.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4080
Not Found: /job-detail/static/assets/plugins/datepicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.cs
```

Comment: Smells like relative url. add leading slash into static file reference in job-detail template. Or show template code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added the leading slash to all my links and it works normally now. Thanks @IvanStarostin